# Terminating a voice call via AT Command

Tags: arduino, gsm, at-command

Im working on a hobby project involving an Arduino and TC35 GSM Module, all is going well really but I am wondering is there an AT Command to terminate a voice call (ATD+phone number;) as I cannot seem to find one in any of the literature I've searched through.

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer to your question is
ATH0 from memory

Answer (score 5):

While the "classic" command `ATH` (there is no need to give a numerical argument to ATH) is applicable for disconnecting calls, notice that it might be configured to do nothing by `AT+CVHU=1` (ignore DTR pin and ATH) for other phones (TC35 seems to not support AT+CVHU).

There is the `AT+CHUP` command that always will hang up the current call, independently of ATH behaviour configuration.

The [27.007](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27007.htm) standard also defines an AT+CHCCS (Hangup of current calls) command that can be used to disconnect calls. Also `AT+CHLD` might be used to disconnect calls.

Comment: +1 Wow, this is the correct answer. For me ATH0 command was working only for some phones, and for others ATH was working. But this command AT+CHUP works like a charm. Thans a lot sir

Answer (score 1):

The command you are looking for is ATH0 (Also dredged from my memory) but then confirmed with the [Official Documentation](http://kurser.iha.dk/eit/mic1/MICDocs/tc35i_atc_0207.pdf)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21108204)

Comment: @Martin This is not a link-only answer. Just "ATH0" completely answers the question (which is also what the accepted answer says).

Answer (score 1):

**ATH** command ends call ONLY **when call was answered**.

**AT+CHUP** command ends call **whenever answered or not**