# Block incoming call (hang-up) using modem

Tags: at-command, modem

I have an USB modem with caller ID enabled. I also have a phone connected with a splitter.

Once I identify the caller ID as bad (not in my white list) I would like to hang up: make the phone stop ringing (as I said I have both a modem and a phone connected to the line). I want to block the incoming call.

What is the correct AT command? I tried with no success:

```
ATH0
AT+CHUP
```

If I have not answered the call, is it technically a "hang up"? 
Can I send a busy tone with an AT command?

Answer (score 0):

### Incoming calls

The phone will allocate all the necessary resources for a call when it receives an incoming call (by the *Call Control* part of the modem's network handling code). You can see that for instance in the `AT+CLCC` command which has the following state values

```
0 active
1 held
2 dialing (MO call)
3 alerting (MO call)
4 incoming (MT call)
5 waiting (MT call)
```

So even if the voice path is not fully set up when the call is still incoming, there definitely is a call to tear down.

### Hanging up calls

Yes, those two commands should be correct (although you do not need the numeric argument, just `ATH` should be fine), and you should be able to hang up an incoming call even though it is not answered yet.

Although I think that is unlikely in your case, notice that there is the `AT+CVHU` command which configures ATH behaviour, and can be configured to ignoring ATH. However, AT+CHUP should always disconnect<sup>1</sup>.

I am [aware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14756791/terminating-a-voice-call-via-at-command/15724321#15724321) of two other commands that might be used, `AT+CHCCS` (Hangup of current calls) and `AT+CHLD`.

Browsing [27.007](https://portal.3gpp.org/desktopmodules/Specifications/SpecificationDetails.aspx?specificationId=1515) I also see AT+CLCK which could possibly be used. It mentions `"AI" BAIC (Barr All Incoming Calls)` which you could possibly turn off and on again, although the network might not support this or even if supported might only apply for later calls. So that would be more of a hackish approach, however the command also lists

```
"NT" barr incoming calls from numbers Not stored to TA memory
"NM" barr incoming calls from numbers Not stored to MT memory
"NS" barr incoming calls from numbers Not stored to SIM/UICC memory
"NA" barr incoming calls from numbers Not stored in Any memory
```

and that sounds like very close to what you want (TA, MT and SIM memory are references to phone book storages, ref `AT+CPMS` (see [27.005](https://portal.3gpp.org/desktopmodules/Specifications/SpecificationDetails.aspx?specificationId=1514))). These values are referring to behaviour local to the modem and is not network related.

So if you just store your white list in your modem's phone book, you might possibly not need to do anything more.

As a last alternative you might try to just start a new outgoing call (possibly to a number that does not answer (your own number ought for instance to work)), hopefully discarding the incoming call (or maybe it changes state to waiting then? Not sure).

---

<sup>1</sup>
In addition to possibly being disabled, ATH might not actually end a call but just change mode in an alternating call, although that is a rather obscure feature probably being phased out in most networks today. But AT+CHUP is guaranteed to disconnect.

Comment: Do I need to enter some mode of the modem before issuing the command ATH or the  alternative commands?

Comment: No, I am not sure what mode that should be.